# Simple Java Error Code while compiling

Tags: java

I am trying to run below code. It is giving me error

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void

```
public class CompStrings{

    String s1=null;
    String s2=null;

    public void testMethod(){


        s1 = new String("Hello");
        s2 = new String("Hello");
        String str3="abc";
        String  str4 ="abc";
        /**
         * ==
         */
        if(str3==str4){
            System.out.println("str3==str4 is true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("str3==str4 is false");
        }

        if(str3.equals(str4)){
            System.out.println("str1.equals(str2) is true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("str1.equals(str2) is false");
        }

        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());

        System.out.println(s1 + " equals " + s2 + " -> " +
        s1.equals(s2));

        System.out.println(s1 + " == " + s2 + " -> " + (s1 == s2)); 
        /*Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
        Integer i2 = new Integer(10);
        System.out.println(i1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(i2.hashCode());
        1)String s1="hello";
        String s2="hello";

        2)String s1 = new String("Hello");
        String s2 = new String("Hello");

        3)String s1="hello";
        string s2=s1;

        **/

    }
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        CompStrings obj= new CompStrings();
//      \System.out.println("Calling My Method"+ obj.testMethod());

    System.out.println("Hashcode for emp1 = " + obj.testMethod());// Here it gives Error



    }


    public boolean equals(Object o){
        String s = (String) o;
        if (s1.equals(s) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }


        }

        public int hashCode(){
        return s1.hashCode();

        }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`testMethod()` obviously doesn't return anything, that's why there's nothing to print.

Answer (score 3):

`testMethod()` doesn't return anything - so what would you expect the result to be when you try to use the value of the expression `testMethod()` for *any* reason? (In this case you happen to be using it in string concatenation, but you couldn't assign it to a variable, pass it as an argument etc either.)

It sounds like you *really* want it to return a hash code, given the rest of the `System.out.println` call. Alternatively:

```
System.out.println("Calling testMethod");
obj.testMethod();
System.out.println("testMethod finished");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `testMethod()` has no return type, if you wish to use it in this way it must return either a String or another Object. I say Object because all objects in Java inherit from Object, and hence will have a toString() implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `obj.testMethod()` return nothing (`void`)... so you can't concat it with a String.

Try this instead:

```
System.out.println("Hashcode for emp1 = ");
obj.testMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be more clean to write like that

String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";

But the problem is that testMethod() does not return a string.... it returns nothing!

Answer (score 0):

`testMethod()` should return `String` instead of `void`.

Or, don't put the call to `testMethod()` inside `System.out.println()`